# Android HoloEverywhere: No top ActionBar/TitleBar on default Holo.Theme issue

Tags: android, actionbarsherlock, android-theme, android-holo-everywhere

I'm using `HoloEverywhere` port for my app and I have this really weird issue: on Gingerbread the default `Holo.Theme` doesn't show the top ActionBar/TitleBar on any of the activity (yes I did go over all my layouts and XMLs manifest for 'silly' mistakes).

However when tested on another phone running JellyBean it worked as expected. (you may argue JB already have Holo Theme built-in... but anyway I'm just stating the fact of what's happening.)

This has frustrated the heck out of me for 2 days already. Any ideas?

Comment: Are you extend activities from org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity?

Comment: I never used HoloEverywhere before, but from what I see you should try making SherlockActivity extend org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity in ABS project. Also try making Holo.Theme parent of Theme.Sherlock in ABS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here's how I fix it:

- Add this to your AndroidManifext.XML

  android:name="org.holoeverywhere.app.Application"
- Add this to your Activity

  import org.holoeverywhere.app.Activity;
- Done.

Answer (score 0):

Gingerbread doesn't have the actionBar feature. It was added in HoneyComb.
If you want to have action bar like HoneyComb/ICS/Jelly bean below 2.3, you need custom the titlebar by yourself.
You can reference my implements about custom title:
[Custom Titlebar Example](https://code.google.com/p/wifi-map-with-nokia-here-api/source/browse/src/com/buptcoder/wifimap/SingleAPMapActivity.java)

Comment: hence the reason I'm using HoloEverywhere Theme port.

Answer (score -1):

I think there may b two problem

1.

```
 android:theme="@android:style/Theme.NoTitleBar"
```

2.
Remove the code If this is Written in `Activity` `Class` , `OnCreate` Method

```
this.requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
this.getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
```

Comment: None of your proposed issues would explain why it works on JellyBean.